# I'm making a Discord Ghostpinger bot in Python

Tags: python

The part that prints out every message does work and it can see messages properly, but it never sends a response (the !ghostping doesn't work).
I'm quite new to Phyton tho so it's a possibility that I am just dumb, thank you if you check it out though <3

```
import time
import discord



TOKEN = ('don't token log my bot pls the token is here btw')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')




@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    full_message = str(message.content)
    user_message = str(message.content).split('!ghostping')[0]
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    print(f'{username}: {str(message.content)} ({channel})')

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.channel.name == 'teszt':
        if str(message.content.lower).startswith('!ghostping'):
         await message.channel.send(f'@{user_message}') #this part doesn't work
         time.sleep(1)
         await ctx.message.delete()
         return


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
user_message = str(message.content).split('!ghostping')[0]
```

and then here:

```
if str(message.content.lower).startswith('!ghostping'):
```

The `await message.channel.send(f'@{user_message}')` works by itself. But you don't reach it. Check this out:

```
>>> message = '!ghostping'
>>> user_messages = str(message).split('!ghostping')[0]
>>> user_messages
''
>>> user_messages = str(message).split('!')
>>> user_messages
['', 'ghostping']
>>> message = '!ghostping 123'
>>> user_messages = str(message).split('!ghostping')
>>> user_messages
['', ' 123']
```

You were trying to do the `if ''` statement. `bool('')` is False.